# Confusion between 'once every' and 'twice/thrice'

Tags: expressions

Are these two expressions the same thing:

1. once every two weeks
2. twice a week

Suppose if I say:

> This magazine is issued only once every two weeks.

Will the following mean the same thing:

> This magazine is issued twice a week.

Do they mean the same?

And where does the term 'biweekly' stand in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This magazine is issued only once every two weeks.

This means you get the delivery or the update of the magazine only **one time** in the **span of two weeks**. Magazines and special edition newspapers usually follow a basic trend of following a schedule. So if you get a magazine today, the next one will be issued on (or before in some cases) November 13th.

> This magazine is issued twice a week.

This means you get the delivery or the update of the magazine **two times** in a **span of one week**. Similar to the previous case, the dates may be fixed, like Monday and Thursday or maybe Saturday and Sunday, likewise.

---

And yes, [biweekly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/biweekly) can be used to mean either every two weeks or twice a week. ***Note: Biweekly, as the meaning says can be used to mean either instance, which will certainly lead to ambiguity. Better avoid it.***

There is a special word for **twice a week** occurrence: [Semiweekly](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/semiweekly) *Occurring twice a week.* (North American usage)

Again, there is another noteworthy word for **once every two weeks** or simply, every two weeks: [Fortnightly](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/fortnightly) *Happening or produced every two weeks.* (British usage) (credits to @rjpond)

Some useful blogs you can refer to:

1. [Bi vs. Semi](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/definitions/bi-vs-semi-weeklymonthlyannually/)
2. [Biweekly vs. Fortnightly vs. Semi-weekly](https://www.spellzone.com/blog/Commonly_Confused_Words_Biweekly_vs_Fortnightly_vs_Semi-weekly.htm)

Comment: So what's the idea behind 'biweekly' and 'fortnightly'? Do they both mean a period of 14 nights or 14 days?

Comment: You can frame that as a new question altogether!

Comment: @SabbirAhmed You can probably find the answers in a dictionary. "Biweekly" is ambiguous, as Dhanishtha Ghosh has already said. "Fortnightly" is unambiguous - it means once every two weeks. "Fortnight" and "fortnightly" are common words in British English, although apparently rarer in the United States.

Comment: Thanks @rjpond. I forgot to include the the definition of _fortnighly_. Do you mind if I include that too? I mean since you commented after I answered, it would seem like I copied it.

Comment: Please feel free. I don't mind at all.